# What is the purpose of Google Pub/Sub?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

So I was looking at using Google's Pub/Sub service for queues but by trial and error I came to a conclusion that I have no idea what it's good for in real applications.

Google says that it's

> A global service for real-time and reliable messaging and streaming
>   data

but the way it work is really strange to me. It holds acked messages up to 7 days, if the subscriber re-subscribes it will get all the messages from the past 7 days even if it already acked them, acked messages will most likely be sent again to the same subscriber that acked them already and there's no FIFO as well.

So I really do not understand how one should use this service if the only thing that it guarantees is that a message will be delivered at least once to any subscriber. This cannot be used for idempotent actions, each subscriber has to store an information about all messages that were acked already so it won't process the message multiple times and so on...

Comment: It should be very rare that a subscriber re-receives a message that it has already acknowledged. If this is happening regularly then I suggest you open a support ticket and a GCP representative will help you determine the cause of the problem.

Comment: Actually it is not rare at all but rather normal. And not as "bug", it is documented behavior. Pubsub guarantees delivery at least once but not only once.

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Pub/Sub has a lot of different applications where decoupled systems need to send and receive messages. The [overview page](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview) offers a number of use cases including balancing work loads, logging, and event notifications. It is true that Google Cloud Pub/Sub does not currently offer any FIFO guarantees and that messages can be redelivered.

However, the fact that the delivery guarantee is "at least once" should not be taken to mean acked messages are redelivered when a subscriber re-subscribers. Redelivery of acked messages is a rare event. This generally only happens when the ack did not make it all the way back to the service due to a networking issue, a machine failure, or some other exceptional condition. While that means that apps do need to be able to handle this case, it does not mean it will happen frequently.

For different applications, what happens on message redelivery can differ. In a case such as cache invalidation, mentioned in the overview page, getting two events to invalidate an entry in a cache just means the value will have to be reloaded an extra time, so there is not a correctness concern.

In other cases, like tracking button clicks or other events on a website for logging or stats purposes, infrequent acked message redelivery is likely not going to affect the information gathered in a significant way, so not bothering to check if events are duplicates is fine.

For cases where it is necessary to ensure that messages are processed exactly once, then there has to be some sort of tracking on the subscriber side to ensure this is the case. It might be that the subscriber is already accessing and updating an underlying database in response to messages and duplicate events can be detected via that storage.

Comment: Of course I can track acked messages in subscriber, the issue is that if I use Pubsub as queue and my workers are ephemeral(kubernetes job) I have no way of tracking this information without a central DB which I can use for the queue in the first place. Therefore my question stands: what is the purpose of PubSub?

Comment: It sounds like you have a very specific use case in mind, so I recommend you update the question with that use case. If your publisher and subscriber are tightly coupled, they have access to a single central database, and the throughput of your queue is relatively small, then it's possible Pub/Sub doesn't necessarily meet the requirements you have. But it is a big leap to then say "I have no idea what it's good for in real applications." I have mentioned cases where at-least-once delivery is not an issue.